# Undefined references to subroutines from an unknown library in Fortran

Tags: function, libraries, gfortran

I have been asked to compile a set of Fortran modules.
It has been many years since dabbling with Fortran.

Using gfortran on Linux Mint I get linker errors on various intrinsic functions;

The first error is

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: in function `_start':
```

Thereafter a series of undefined references to functions such as plm_, gettim_ , texta_, wstrin_   and many  others.
These are associated to calls in the source code; CALL PLM, CALL GETTIM and so on.

How can I find the libraries that references these functions. I have tried installing various libraries with apt but so far no success.

Comment: Hou should certainly show the *complete* error output.

Comment: The entire output is voluminous. The first error is because the compiler needs to be told which module is the start. You'd think it could work that out since the starting module begins with the word PROGRAM. I can pu the module name as a flag in the compile line. i thought the libraries might be somewhere in the Linux set of libraries but I have searched them all and there is nothing. The original code was compiled using  16 bit Windows so I need to start searching on a Windows platform.

Comment: Start by searching the web. A websearch finds GETTIM in the IFPORT library. For other symbols, well, you have to show them otherwise no one can say anything about them. No one can tell you where to find "and so on".

Comment: GETTIM being (I imagine get time) is found as you say in the IFPORT library.

Comment: Here are other undefined references but her elimited by max num charactrs and time to edit.
/usr/bin/ld: MMR25.FOR:(.text+0x11eb): undefined reference to `wstrin_'
`mouses_'
`borpro_'
`mmrb_'
`axial_'
`doit_'
`checky_'
rkey_'
`colour_'
`doit_
'`window_'
`colors_'
`graph_'
and many more. this may be a Windows library. I am trying Visual Studio but there again a bit of a learning experience. I would love to find what the library is and use gfortran

Comment: Use [edit] to put all the important information into your question. Do not use comments.